# Combining Jquery statements

Tags: jquery

I wondered if anyone can help  me!

I have two separate jQuery statements on my site which basically act on a div that when clicked, will expand a content zone that is hidden by a negative margin on the right of the screen.

What I want to do is have several of these elements on each page, but I want something as streamlined as possible where I don't have to keep adding a whole new statement per element!

Here is a link to the website in question (the elements are on the right - one with a Plus sign, the other below with a Twitter icon)

[Sandbanks Property](http://www.sandbanksproperty.co.uk/)

Below is the code I have:

//Setting up the functions:

```
function extraOn() {
var w = $('.homeplus-expanded').width();
$('.homeplus-expanded').animate ({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':'0px'
    }, 'fast');
}


function extraOff() {
var ws = $('.homeplus-expanded').innerWidth();
$('.homeplus-expanded').animate({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':-ws
    },'fast'); 
}



function shareOn() {
var w = $('.homeplus-expanded').width();
$('.shareplus-expanded').animate ({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':'0px'
    }, 'fast');
}


function shareOff() {
var sp = $('.shareplus-expanded').innerWidth();
$('.shareplus-expanded').animate({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':-sp
    },'fast'); 
}
```

//and then calling these functions onClick:

```
$('.homeplus').click(function(){
extraOn();
});


$('.homeplus-expanded span.close').click(function(){
extraOff();
    });

$('.shareplus').click(function(){
shareOn();
});


$('.shareplus-expanded span.close').click(function(){
shareOff();
    });
```

As you can see, I'm sure there is some cross over and some room for making the code a lot neater and more modular....

Thanks for any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your duplicate code and move it to function. Then pass the corresponding handler to the function to bind click event. Since the binded click event function is in function scope, it is visible to the click event. Try to do more refactoring for your code :). Code refactoring is funny and the refactored code can reuse and easy for maintenance.

The simplified version as below.

```
function InitContentZone(turnOnElement, turnOffElement, expandElement)
{
    var expandEle = expandElement;
    function extraOn() {
        $(expandEle).animate ({
            right : '0',
            'margin-right':'0px'
        }, 'fast');
    }

    function extraOff() {
        var ws = $(expandEle).innerWidth();
        $(expandEle).animate ({
            right : '0',
            'margin-right':-ws
        }, 'fast');
    }

    $(turnOnElement).click(extraOn);
    $(turnOffElement).click(extraOff);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    InitContentZone('.homeplus', '.homeplus-expanded span.close', '.homeplus-expanded');
    InitContentZone('.shareplus', '.shareplus-expanded span.close', '.shareplus-expanded');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Derek, I think this looks like what I was looking for. As you guessed, I am using the innerWidth function to hide the clicked element and show the other element.

Comment: This looks like modular, expandable and future proof! :)

Comment: I've just tried that out - it works so well! It's just such an elegant solution! Just one thing, I want the element that has been clicked on to hide itself when clicked, and then reappear when the close button on the expandElement is clicked - I'm guessing I would use .innerWidth on this one too - but not sure how to do this without destroying the elegance!!

Comment: You would do the same things that I did in the InitContentZone. Just think of the code that is re-usable and put it inside.

Comment: Like this? Oh dear... `var expandEle = expandElement;
 var turnOnEle = turnOnElement;
    function extraOn() {
 var sh = $(turnOnEle).innerWidth();
        $(expandEle).animate ({right : '0','margin-right':'0px'}, 'fast');
  $(turnOnEle).animate ({right : '0','margin-right':-sh }, 'fast');
    }`

Comment: The above does work, but I wanted to combine a nice animation on the buttons with the following....which seems to reset the above thus not hiding the 'click' element: `$('.homeplus,.shareplus').live({
 mouseenter: function(){$(this).stop(true,true).animate({ 'marginRight' : '10px' }, 150 );},mouseleave: function(){$(this).stop(true,true).animate({ 'marginRight' : '0' }, 150 );}});`

Comment: Almost, you should think and identify what you are going to do and refactor the code to have tiny and clear structure.

Comment: Hi Derek, sorry to bother you! I'm really struggling to work the above animation on the button element in to your code. Is there any chance when you get a moment you can take another look for me?

Comment: OK, contact me via email. You can my contact in my profile/blog.

Answer (score 0):

use a single function that uses the `$(this)` selector, and call it from the `click` event handlers. So eg :

```
function turnOn() {
  var w = $(this).width();
  $(this).animate ({
    right : '0',
   'margin-right':'0px'
  }, 'fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference to the element that has been clicked onto the "extraOn" and other functions, then use this reference as the jquery selector

```
// Call it like this 
extraOn(this);

function extraOn(elem) {
  var w = $(elem).width(); // No idea what this is for
  $(elem).animate ({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':'0px'
    }, 'fast');
  }
}
```

Or you can use the extraOn function content as the actual callback, this way you can also use the event, like so:

```
$('.homeplus').click(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // if it is a <a> element or has some other default behaviour
  var w = $(this).width(); // No idea what this is for
  $(this).animate ({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':'0px'
    }, 'fast');
  }
});
```

If you are expecting to load these elements through ajax, you may prefer to use a deferred event handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.homeplus',function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // if it is a <a> element or has some other default behaviour
  var w = $(this).width(); // No idea what this is for
  $(this).animate ({
    right : '0',
    'margin-right':'0px'
    }, 'fast');
  }
});
```

Comment: There's some interesting ideas here and it looks pretty short and sweet, however I think Derek below offers a slightly more complete and all encompassing method for my situation...thank you so much for your time though